# Change background color of multiple buttons on SwiftUI

Tags: ios, button, ipad, swiftui

I have a problem that I can't solve. I would like to change the background color of one button among others when the user taps on it.

So I made this code

```
ForEach(allWords, id: \.self) { myRow in
Button{
    if (self.didTap == true){
        self.didTap = false
    }
    else {
        self.didTap = true
    }
    self.variableTitle = myRow
    isNight.toggle()
} label:{
    ULD(title: myRow, textColor: .black, backgroundColor: didTap ? .red : .green)
}
```

Where I retrieve a list of words in allWords and myRow contains at each time the title that I have on the button.

The problem is that when I tap on one button all buttons change their color but I would like to change only the color of one button that I have tapped.

Can you help me on this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have one variable `didTap` for each `Button`. This can be achieved by moving the button to a separate view.

You can create this view:

```
struct MyButton: View {

    @State private var didTap = false    // This will change the color

    let myRow: String    // I'm assuming it's a String, otherwise use the correct type

    @Binding var isNight: Bool   // This will change the variable in the parent view
    @Binding var variableTitle: String   // This will change the variable in the parent view (always assuming it's a String)

    var body: some View {
                Button{
                    didTap.toggle()
                    variableTitle = myRow
                    isNight.toggle()
                } label:{
                    ULD(title: myRow, textColor: .black, backgroundColor: didTap ? .red : .green)
                }
    }
}
```

Then, in your parent view just call it as per the following example. Remember that `isNight` and `variableTitle` **must** both be a `@State` variable in the parent view.

```
ForEach(allWords, id: \.self) { myRow in
    MyButton(myRow: myRow, isNight: $isNight, variableTitle: $variableTitle)
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. 
Yet, I have a problem now with your view I have this message
Type 'MyButton' does not conform to protocol 'View'
And also this one 
Cannot find type 'view' in scope
I don't understand because I have already imported the SwiftUI

Comment: @ThomThomPhao: sorry, I made a typo - I wrote `var body: some view` instead of `var body: some View`. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var allWords = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4"]
    @State var allSelectedWords = Set<String>()
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(allWords, id: \.self) { myRow in
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                Button(action:{
                    if allSelectedWords.contains(myRow) {
                        allSelectedWords.remove(myRow)
                    } else {
                        allSelectedWords.removeAll()
                        allSelectedWords.insert(myRow)
                    }
                }){
                    Text(myRow)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(allSelectedWords.contains(myRow) ? .red : .green)
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
}
```